# Conditional count

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I want functions which will:

- add +1 to cell I3 for every `W`, `L`, `T`, `IP` and `R` in cells from F8 to F10, so now it has to be `3` because cells F8, F9 and F10 are populated:

[image: Table]

If F11 were populated also, then it has to be `4`.

- in J3 put only the count of `W` from cells from F8 to F10; to K3 only  the count of `L`, etc. .....

NOTE : KDYŽ = IF , SUMA = SUM ------- in my language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count any entries use:

```
=COUNTA(F8:F20)
```

To count specific entries use:

```
=COUNTIF(F8:F20,"W")
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right you just want to count how many lines are filled? Then use COUNTA function in cell i3 and use range of f8 cell down to how many you want to check. [Here](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a?CorrelationId=4a5fa53b-704a-4758-a1e8-e600b94f7fbd&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) is some documentation.

For specific count like win and loses use COUNIF function with syntax like this =COUNTIF(F8:F11,"a"). change F11 to your desired range and a with W or L or whatever you want.
Hope it helps.

Comment: yes thats one problem, second is that i want to know how much cells are filled only with W, how much are filled only with L etc. , becouse i have 5 things that i write to F -> W / L / T / IP / R  , doesnt matter what it means, but i want to count them all  together, and then count how much W´s are there, how much L´s etc..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest change J1 to `W`, K1 to `L` etc and in J3 and copied across to suit:

```
  =COUNTIF($F8:$F22,J1)
```

then in I3:

```
=SUM(J3:N3)
```